# Worklight Server 6.1 startup error

Tags: worklight-server

Error during startup of server (WAS 8.5, WL 6.1)

```
0000006f JeeProjectAct E com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator contextInitialized FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /worklight [project worklight]

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/<my worklight install path>/Worklight/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'brokerSessionFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerSessionFactory' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/<my worklight install path>/WorklightServer/worklight-jee-library.jar!/conf/spring-server-core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
```

Answer (score 0):

In WebSphere, visit Environment -> Shared Libraries. You should have a WL_PLATFORM_LIB - open this and check the box for:

> Use an isolated class loader for this shared library

I'm not sure why this is needed, or what impact it has elsewhere, but it will enable your worklight server to startup without errors.